# How to check for API compatibility between Ruby versions?

Tags: ruby, rubocop

Our team maintains a ruby script that must support any ruby >= 1.9.3 (yes, that's a pretty old ruby version but this is something outside our control at the moment). Recently, we added a change that included the verification of a regexp using `match?` and everything was going well until one of the users reported that the script was exploding for ruby 2.3 with the message:

```
undefined method `match?' for #<Regexp:0x000000018471e0> (NoMethodError)
```

Turns out this happens because the `match?` method is available in ruby >= 2.4.

We have been running `ruby -c script.rb` with multiple versions of ruby (1.9.3, 2.0.0, 2.1.10, 2.3.7, 2.5.1, 2.6.3, 2.7.4) as part of our test suite and this didn't show up as a syntax error and I suspect it's because the actual syntax is "correct" but the method is simply not available in some versions of ruby. We also tried [rubocop](https://github.com/rubocop/rubocop), hoping that it could detect these incompatibility issues but it doesn't report any error either.

So, my question is, what's the best way to check for this API compatibility issues between multiple ruby versions?

Comment: How does your test suite look like? What kind of tests does it run? Where does it run those tests, on a CI server, a CI service (like Circle CI, Travis CI, Github Actions, Buildkite, etc)?

Comment: Our test suite has unit and integration tests and, additionally, runs `ruby -c` for all .rb files as I mentioned in the question. All of this runs in our own CI servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `ruby -c` with the oldest Ruby you support is a good start, as it will detect if you are trying to use a newer syntax.

For using methods that are new:

1. Run your tests suite in both the oldest and newest Ruby versions you want to support.
2. Consider using my [`backports` gem](https://github.com/marcandre/backports/) to make it possible to use newer API even on old Rubies. For example, it includes `Regexp.match?` among the hundreds of backports...

Comment: I think you described the two parts of the problem very well: 1) using newer syntax, 2) using newer methods. We're covering for 1 but not for 2, and running the tests in all the versions of ruby should have caught the problem. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Do you have an automated test suite? If so, you can set up your CI to test against multiple Ruby versions, e.g.:

https://github.com/actions/setup-ruby#usage

(Edit: I see you did mention a test suite, so it sounds like you have a gap in the test coverage, or you're not running the tests against each Ruby version?).

Comment: Yes, we have an automated test suite and we don't have a gap in test coverage but we're not running the suite against each ruby version so, as you mention, doing that should help us catch these issues in the future :)